# Create a full url link in Action Mailer without a url helper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, link-to

We have an application with a javascript front-end that uses [navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) library to create routes.

I would like to create a link in a email using the navigo notation. The problem is that if I create a link with `link_to` passing only the path to navigo, like this:

```
link_to 'Some link', '/#/some/custom/path'
```

it will, as it should, put only the `/#/some/custom/path` in the link `href` attribute.

According to Rails Guides, if I set the config:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

It will add the host to links created with link_to in the mailer.

Question is, since I'm not using the `path` or `url` notation with link_to, how could I create a link to the site, that uses this host property? (Because we have staging, and production servers, and the address can change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the action_mailer options

```
link_to 'Some link',  Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] + '/#/some/custom/path'
```

Will give you `'example.com/#/some/custom/path'`

Comment: Yep, still feel kind of hacky, but the best solution I could find.

Comment: Not really hacky, because that's how the url helper works. It just doens't look too pretty